# Internal microphone becomes unavailable when plugging in headset

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

Upon plugging in my AKG headset, PulseAudio automatically changes to the external microphone. However, my headset has no external microphone, and I want to use my laptop's internal microphone - but it becomes unavailable (see pic)

[image]

When I disconnect the headset, the microphone becomes available again.